# Bone scale vs vertex scale

Tags: bones, coordinates

[image]

The vertices and the bones seem to be working with a different coordinate system. In the image, the bone and vertex at roughly the same height are mis-scaled by a factor of 40. When I export it into my own format, the matrix transformations have the same misaligned value.

When I select the model, it says it's at 25% scale, which only increases the difference between the two quantities.

How do I find the conversation rate between the two or force them to line up?

Comment: Data like bones and vertices use local coordinates. To have them "line up" would need the origin points same (it appears you have) , and have unity scale on both armature and mesh objects, it sounds like you don't.. You say the mesh obj has scale 0.25, my guess is armature is scaled 0.1 and is parent of mesh, hence verts locally  be 40x bones.  Simply make scales of both objects (1, 1, 1) to avoid other hassles down the line.    btw, the vertex illustrated is a pole (has more than 4 connected edges) and will also cause hassles.

Comment: Alright. The armature's scale appeared to be 1,1,1, but if you say they should be the same scale I'll try to find where it's happening. What's wrong with "poles"? I read that "Poles used improperly will result in pinching when smoothed." and another place that says something about smoothing in the context of animation. Fixing it is easy enough, but what problem am I preventing?

Comment: No expert on topo, As a rule of thumb for quads try and keep poles to 3s like a cube corner and 5s.